Were other robots in Battlestar Galactica animals in suits?
Muffit the daggit was played by a three year old chimpanzee in a suit. It seems potentially very cruel.
Were other robots in Battlestar Galactica animals in suits?





Just to be clear, the core of this question is whether other science fiction works had animals playing robots? Because a fair amount of this seems to instead be focusing on whether it was ethical to do so.

Yes. The question is about animals playing robots.

https://boingboing.net/2017/02/24/muffit-the-daggit-was-played-b.html an interesting featurette. Apparently the monkey was well-treated, but occasionally moody.

So far as I recall of the Battlestar Galactica universe... the 2004 series had no animals, robotic or otherwise. Galactica 1980 took place almost exclusively on Earth of 1980, so the only robots were the Cylons. That leaves the original series, of which I believe Daggit was the only robotic animal. There was an episode ("Greetings From Earth") featuring two non-Cylon robots portrayed by actors Bobby Van and Ray Bolger, doing a Laurel-and-Hardy-like schtick. I think a couple of episodes had real animals dressed to portray live alien animals, but not robotic animals.

@Valorum  A chimpanzee is not a monkey, not any more than you are.

I was a Battlestar Galactica convention in NYC  where there was a version of Muffit the Daggit which seemed quite convincing.  I don't know who or what was inside the suit.
